# Split image in sectors

Tags: python, image

I'm a math teacher and I'd like to make a small program in python to show some concepts of [permutation groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_group), what I want to do is to have an image like the following one and split the 'sectors' with the numbers to work with them separatedly (they will change colors). Which library can I use to do this kind of stuff?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Pillow Python Imaging Library (Fork)](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow). But i think simple to do this in graphical editor.

Comment: something like adobe after effects or something similar. In such programs it is much easier to work with images.

Comment: the point is that the user will interact with it, and the colors of the sectors will change according to the action, in fact there will be more circles connected between them, so there are a lot of possibilities to the configuration of the colors.

Comment: hmm then it is easier to use javascript with raphael js lybrary. It's much simple to create it interactive